# Executing Item check code in Quickbooks PHP

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am working on PHP API in QuickBooks. I have created some pages and they are all working with my Sandbox account. But When I am trying to do the same for live account, it is giving me errors. I have changed the variable $sandbox=true to $sandbox=false in config.php

below is the code for itemchk.php

```
<?php
//require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/views/header.tpl.php';
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
$tokenval = '';
$customerkey = '';
$customersecreat = '';
if(isset($_POST['tokenval']) && $_POST['tokenval'] != ''){
    $tokenval = $_POST['tokenval'];
}   
if(isset($_POST['customerkey']) && $_POST['customerkey'] != ''){
    $customerkey = $_POST['customerkey'];
}
if(isset($_POST['customersecreat']) && $_POST['customersecreat'] != ''){
    $customersecreat = $_POST['customersecreat'];
}
$quers = "ItemChkQueryRs";
if(trim($tokenval) != "" && trim($customerkey) != "" && trim($customersecreat) != ""){  
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config1.php';
    $ItemService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Item();
    if(isset($_POST['Itemname']) && $_POST['Itemname'] != ''){
        $Itemname=$_POST['Itemname'];
        $Items = $ItemService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Item where name='".$Itemname."' ");
        if (count($Items)){
            $status = 'Success'; 
            $statuscode =  '0';
            $status_message =  'Item Exist';
            $Item = $Items[0];
            $txnid = $Item->getId();
            $txnid = str_replace("{-", "", $txnid);
            $txnid = str_replace("}", "", $txnid);
        }
        else{
            $statuscode =  '0';
            $status_message =  'Item does not Exist';
        }   

    }
    else{
        $statuscode =  '1';
        $status_message =  'Item Name Missing';
    }   
    include_once "show_xml1.php";
}
else{
    $statuscode =  '1';
    $status_message =  'Missing Authentication Details';
    include_once "show_xml1.php";
}   

?>
```

The errors I am getting while executing this page are

```
Notice: Undefined variable: Context in /home2/ultrasou/public_html/garg.com/quickbooks/ItemChk1.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined variable: realm in /home2/ultrasou/public_html/garg.com/quickbooks/ItemChk1.php on line 27

Fatal error: Call to a member function IPP() on a non-object in /home2/ultrasou/public_html/garg.com/quickbooks/QuickBooks/IPP/Service.php on line 829
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you reconnect to your live QuickBooks after changing `$sandbox` to `FALSE`?

You'll  need to, and it doesn't look like you did...

Comment: So it worked the first time, and you marked it as the answer, and now it suddenly didn't work the first time? Please clarify.

Comment: Earlier the person working on it said it is fine.So I marked it as answer. now they say, they haven't tested at that time for live. Can you pls tell me how to reconnect and how to verify the connection is active?

Comment: Click the [Connect to QuickBooks] button. Try to transfer data, see if it works.